How to solve WebView2Loader.dll not found error?
I'm currently facing an error that says

The code execution cannot proceed because WebView2Loader.dll was not
found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem.

I downloaded "Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime" and thought that it fixed the problem, but I still get the same error. How can I solve this error?


Can you tell us more about the application? This seems more like a configuration problem.. Based on the existing Stack Overflow questions on this particular error, suspect it's a duplicate, over at Stack Overflow and not a question that should exist here at Super User.

It happens when I open my laptop, not in a specific app. But I think it all started when I uninstalled McAfee Security; maybe that's the problem.

You didn't mention this fact. Still sounds like a configuration problem as you shouldn't have to install WebView2 to run the software.


I am currently facing an error that says

The code execution cannot proceed because WebView2Loader.dll was not
found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem.


Run the McAfee Software Removal Tool. Since this problem started after you uninstalled a McAfee product, completing the uninstallation of all McAfee products on your system, should resolve this error.
This error is often linked to McAfee software not being completely uninstalled on a system. The missing file can be several different files, in this case, it's Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime.
